# SSIS package Developed in VS 2012 is not running after deployed in Server having SQL server 2012 and VS 2010

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, ssis, bids

I have developed a SSIS package using VS 2012 and i have deployed the same package successfully in another server which has SQL server 2012, but this server has VS 2010 installed, Now i am getting error when executing the deployed package using script in that server.

My friend told me that, this issue is due to the VS version difference between development machine(VS 2012) and deployment server(VS 2012).

please let me know whether my deployment server also need upgrade to VS 2012 for executing my package?

**Way of Execution :**

I am executing the package from SSMS, "Right click the deployed package - > Execute"

**Actual Error Messages :**

The package failed to load due to error 0XC0010014 “One 
or more error occurred There should be more specific 
errors preceding this one that explains the details of the 
errors. This message is used as a return value from 
functions that encounter errors”  This occurs when 
CPackage::LoadFromXML fails

Package:Error Package migration from version 8 to 
version 6 failed with error 0XC001700A “The version 
number in the package is not valid. The version number 
cannot be greater than current version number”

Package:Error The version number in the package is not 
valid The version number cannot be greater than current 
version number

**Purpose of the package :**

This is a sample package for the deployment testing, i have used a single transformation for source to destination transfer.

Comment: VS versions: 2005, 2008, 2010, 2012, 2013, 2015. SQL Server versions: 2005, 2008/2008 R2, 2012, 2014. Whether you use VS 2010 or 2012, you're generating SSIS packages that target SQL Server 2012. VS 2013 targets SQL Server 2014. Otherwise, it's a match between VS number and SQL Server

Comment: What's the actual error? What is the script doing? How are you running the packages on the server? Please click the edit button and update your question with that information.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i have edited my question with the requested information, please let me know if you require any more details on this.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue with VS2013 and VS2012. I developed package on VS2012 and deployed on server having VS2013. Before deployment my SSIS solution got upgraded to support VS2013 and it executed successfully. But when I tried to use the same solution in VS2012, it failed. Apparently you can run your solution in higher version but not in lower version. In your case you need to upgrade your server to VS2012 to execute your SSIS package.